# Return hours, minutes and seconds left if column wasn't updated

Tags: postgresql, update, timestamp, interval

I currently have this query:

```
UPDATE MyTable 
SET    next_update = now() at time zone 'utc' 
WHERE  next_update::timestamp < now() at time zone 'utc' - interval '1 day';
```

Which updates the column `next_update` if a day has passed since the last `next_update` was set. But in the case the value couldn't be updated (a day hasn't passed yet) How can I return the hours, minutes and seconds left for update?

Comment: return where, a function, a variable?

Comment: Returning the remaining time for update with those values to display on the Python program that does the queries. @McNets

Comment: Use a function that a) updates the table and returns for example 0 or b) do not update the table and returns the remaining time.

Comment: Do you have an additional predicate, for example the primary key? Otherwise, what should happen when there are several rows that is not update?

Comment: @Lennart Yes, I do. I took them out for the query right now but there's another condition.

Comment: I would check the number of rows updated, if 0, select the remaining time.

Comment: @Lennart So you mean doing two separate queries? In this case wouldn't it be better then to check first on the Python script the result of a select query that gives me True/False (False if a day didn't pass) and if it's False then update the row?

Comment: Please start any such question by declaring the version of Postgres in use and the relevant table definition (`CREATE TABLE` statement).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a *single* query, I suggest a [data-modifying CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING) like:

```
WITH cte(bound) AS (SELECT now() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' - interval '1 day')
   , upd AS (
   UPDATE MyTable 
   SET    next_update = now() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' 
   FROM   cte
   WHERE  next_update < cte.bound  -- why cast to timestamp?
   )
SELECT *, next_update - cte.bound AS time_to_update
FROM   MyTable, cte
WHERE  next_update >= cte.bound;
```

The point being that `UPDATE` and `SELECT` see the same snapshot and `SELECT` won't return the newly updated rows. (The fist CTE named `cte` is just for convenience, so we don't have to repeat the calculation of the bound.)

`time_to_update` is an `interval` of the form `23:53:27.141289` - *hours:minutes:seconds:µs*. Negative if there can be future timestamps - and possibly with leading days then: `'-26 days -23:58:35.25222'`. Else it cannot be greater than 24h in this query.

Assuming `next_update` is type `timestamp`, though the casts in your `UPDATE` are inconclusive (contradictory). `now() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'` produces a `timestamp`, makes sense if `next_update` is of that type. But then why `next_update::timestamp`? (And why update a column named *"next_update"* to `now()`? Does not seem to make sense.)

Comment: Yeah it was my mistake, next_update should be now() + 1 day, not just now().